# how to convert function output into list, dict or as data frame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function, loops, output

My issue is, i don't know how to use the output of a function properly. The output contains multiple lines (j = column , i = testresult)
I want to use the output for some other rules in other functions. (eg. if (i) testresult > 5 then something)

I have a function with two loops. The function goes threw every column and test something. This works fine.

```
def test():    

    scope = range(10)
    scope2 = range(len(df1.columns))
    for (j) in scope2:
          for (i) in scope:
              if df1.iloc[:,[j]].shift(i).loc[selected_week].item() > df1.iloc[:,[j]].shift(i+1).loc[selected_week].item():
                  i + 1
              else:
                print(j,i)
                
                break
```

Output:
test()

```
1 0
2 3
3 3
4 1
5 0
6 6
7 0
8 1
9 0
10 1
11 1
12 0
13 0
14 0
15 0
```

I tried to convert it to list, dataframe etc. However, i miss something here.

What is the best way for that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix of your code would be:

```
def test():    
    out = []
    scope = range(10)
    scope2 = range(len(df1.columns))
    for j in scope2:
        for i in scope:
            if df1.iloc[:,[j]].shift(i).loc[selected_week].item() <= df1.iloc[:,[j]].shift(i+1).loc[selected_week].item():
                 out.append([i, j])
    return pd.DataFrame(out)

out = test()
```

But you probably don't want to use loops as it's slow, please clarify what is your input with a minimal reproducible example and what you are trying to achieve (expected output and logic), we can probably make it a vectorized solution.

Comment: Thank you mozway. It worked, with small adjustements. In my use case i have a selected time (selected_week). For that week only, some test should be perfomed for each column. In the example above, how many times the value increased compare to past (shift). Do you think the loop is for that okey or do you have a  better way?

Comment: It depends on the exact data and logic